# Sampling from posterior predictive distribution

Tags: statistics, random-sampling

First post. I'm working on this problem using Bayesian methods. In desperation I'm considering using p-values (shock horror), specifically posterior predictive p-values. So I need to simulate from the posterior predictive. I don't see a lot of statistics stuff here - it's mostly applied math at the moment. I could take this to stats.sx I suppose, but this is definitely a computational problem, so I thought I'd give it a shot here. If there are any Bayesians lurking here, now would be a good time to delurk. :-)

In what follows, the hats denote predictive values. Consider

Let $p(\mathbf{p})$ be a Dirichlet prior.

\begin{align*}
p(\mathbf{p}) = (k-1)! I(\sum p_i = 1)
\end{align*}

Let the likelihood be

\begin{align*}
p(y| \mathbf{p}) =  \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{f_i}
\end{align*}

This is the likelihood for a sequence of categorical variables. Assume the prior predictive is (calculation omitted)

\begin{align*}
  p(y) = (k-1)! \frac{\prod_i f_i!}{(N + k - 1)!}
\end{align*}

We obtain

\begin{align*}
  p(\mathbf{p}|y) = p(\mathbf{p}) p(y| \mathbf{p}) / p(y)
                  = \frac{ (k-1)! I(\sum p_i = 1) \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{f_i} }
                          { (k-1)! \frac{\prod_i f_i!}{(N + k - 1)!} }
\end{align*}

Dividing we obtain the posterior

\begin{align*}
  p(\mathbf{p}|y) = \frac{ I(\sum p_i = 1) \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{f_i} (N + k - 1)! }{ \prod_i f_i! }
\end{align*}

Define $f^{\prime}_i = f_i + \hat{f}_i$, and $N^{\prime} =
N+\hat{N}$. Then the posterior predictive is (calculation omitted but can be added if anyone cares)

\begin{align*}
  p(\hat{y}|y) = \int p(\hat{y}|\mathbf{p}) p(\mathbf{p}|y) d\mathbf{p}
                 = \frac{ \prod_i f^{\prime}_i! }{ \prod_i f_i! } \frac{ (N + k - 1)! }{(N^{\prime}+k-1)!}
\end{align*}

So, can anyone suggest methods, preferably as efficient and simple as possible, to simulate from $p(\tilde{y}|y)$? This is a finite distribution, but too big to enumerate. At the moment, I'm not even sure what distribution it is. Thanks in advance.

PS. Can some kind person create "bayesian-computation" and "statistics" tags, and tag this message with them? "random" is not very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Try asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ - actually that seems to be my answer to a lot of qs on here.... problem?

Comment: @Spacedman I think the two overlap nicely - I've started suggesting for a small number of qs over there that they come here.

Comment: I thought the idea with SE was that overlapping fields would live on one site with a tag. I'm wondering if this scicomp site is a good idea now... We'll see.

Comment: @Spacedman: Well, I thought the idea was for this site to be a sort of meta-computation site akin to SO for programming. I'd be disappointed if it turns into a purely applied maths affair. Maybe part of the reason is that currently applied math people have nowhere else to go on SE. Which makes me wonder if lots of bioinformatics people are going to show up too. I just posted on stats.sx chat suggesting people visit here. Maybe I should post on meta stats too.

Comment: @EpiGrad: See my response to Spacedman.

Comment: @Spacedman I think this fits squarely in the realm for this site since the question is "Can anyone suggest methods, preferably as efficient and simple as possible, to simulate from" a given probability distribution.  That is a computational questions (though one that does come up in statistics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best (only?) way to accomplish this will be through Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo

This will allow you to sample from the unknown posterior without knowing it's functional form.

---

These are really more like questions than a better answer, but this seemed the best place to put them:

First, you can reformulate the problem in terms of only $k-1$ unknowns since the last one is functionally dependent (the $p$'s must sum to one).

Assuming $f_i$ represents the observed frequency of each case (please correct that assumption if it's wrong), why include it as part of the prior? I'd suggest that your prior should not depend on the data. You might use an exponent of 0 to represent a vague prior instead.

Unless $k$ is huge, this problem is easily solved by MCMC. You could set it up in Winbugs or PyMC if you don't want to write your own code. Also, with MCMC, the above derivations aren't needed. You only need to specify the prior (which may just be constant) and the likelihood (which is pretty simple).

I'd also suggest not trying to simulate the posterior predictive directly, but instead simulate the posterior first and then the predictive is easily obtained from that by simulation.

Comment: Hmm, I thought someone might say MCMC. I was hoping for something else. MCMC is notoriously computation intensive. Any idea what distribution this is? Also, any tips about doing it specifically in this case?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Ah, I did miss the "preferably as efficient and simple as possible" part of your question, so I see how MCMC might not be a great answer. As for your other questions, I'll think more about them, but unfortunately, as my "(only?)" remark suggests, I may not be much help.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks for answering. I actually did my thesis in an MCMC related area (perfect sampling), so I know it is not that easy to use in practice, and to be honest, tend to run in the opposite direction when it is mentioned.:-) But maybe this question is easier than my thesis topic - I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @FahheemMitha If you *do* use MCMC, depending on what kind of software you're using to perform the computation, you can sample directly from the posterior. See http://confounding.net/2011/08/19/sampling-from-a-bayesian-posterior-distribution-in-sas/, though it's fairly inefficient as these things go.

Comment: The prior was incorrect - careless cutting and pasting. It should be the uninformative Dirichlet prior, no term in $f_i$. Fixed now.

Comment: The posterior $p(\mathbf{p}|y)$ is Dirichlet, no need to use simulation for that. If you are suggesting generating from $p(\mathbf{p}|y)$, then plugging the simulated thetas into $p(\hat{y}|\mathbf{p})$ to get values from $p(\hat{y}|y)$, that's what I'm currently doing (sorry, I should have mentioned that) but it is very ugly and inefficient. Anyway, this approach doesn't actually need MCMC at all, as far as I can see.

Comment: I actually was unfamiliar with the Dirichlet distribution, but it sounds like we are on the same page and I agree that if you have a way to perform the sampling then no MCMC is needed.

Comment: That said, from my perspective, I don't see what is particularly ugly about this solution. This article makes it look pretty straightforward: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_number_generation

Comment: @Barron: I guess I was secretly hoping someone would say - oh, it is such and such distribution! Or you can trivially obtain it from such and such distribution. Simulating directly from parametric distributions is much more painless. One problem I often have is that my handwritten code is too slow, and I have to optimize. NB: I won't see comments that aren't appended to a question or answer I wrote unless you put @ followed by my username in front of the comment. Also, FYI, Dirichlet is the conjugate prior of the multinomial, so you frequently see them together.

Comment: @FaheemMitha OK, I asked a smarter colleague to take a look, crack a book or two, etc., and this is what we've come up with: The predictive distribution for the binomial case is the [Beta-binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution), so we suspect that the predictive distribution for the multinomial is the [Multivariate Polya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_P%C3%B3lya_distribution). Hopefully that's a little closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Barron. That's very helpful and useful. I guess the question is then whether there is any method to simulate from it aside from the method discussed above.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Unfortunately, it seems that your current approach might actually be the best way to do it. Sorry to waste so much time, but perhaps it wasn't a total loss.

Comment: Not at all. It was a useful discussion. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you may (or may not) want to expand your answer to include some of the material in the comments, including a more explicit description of how to simulate, and the name of the distribution. Just in case anyone passes this way who cares.